# How to exclude CSS module files from jest test suites?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I have react component to test, I import its CSS using webpack as the following.

```
 import styles from '../../node_modules/openlayers/css/ol.css' // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
```

After running jest I get error:

```
C:\Users\...\node_modules\openlayers\css\ol.css:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){.ol-box {
                                                                                             ^
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

How to exclude css files from jest test suites?

Comment: @Thomas this is the comment of the year

Answer (score 29):

Or better yet, add

```
yarn add --dev identity-obj-proxy
```

And add the following to jest.config.json

```
{
  "jest":{
     "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(css|less|scss|sass)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: npm i --save-dev identity-obj-proxy   (with npm)

Answer (score 26):

You can create your own mock in `jest` to prevent processing of `css` files.

```
// __mocks__/styleMock.js

module.exports = {};
```

Then in your `package.json` you can map any `css` files to the `styleMock.js` file under `moduleNameMapper` option:

```
"jest": {
  ...
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    ...
    "\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js"
  },
  ..
},
```

See https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/webpack.html#handling-static-assets
for more info.

Comment: This post describes how to handle this issue in several different testing suites. https://diessi.ca/blog/how-to-exclude-css-images-anything-from-unit-tests/